# Firebase admin SDK Python - 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'signer'

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-admin

I am trying to get the Firebase Admin with Python to work, and It seems to be working perfectly on my dev_server, when trying it out locally.

But when I try it on an app engine instance, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'signer'
```

Since it works on the local server, I can't figure out what is wrong. Anybody got a clue?

Note that I have initialised it with:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

And then trying to create the token with:

```
custom_token = auth.create_custom_token(uid)
```

Comment: I have basically the same code working fine on App Engine. How do you package firebase_admin and google-auth libraries into your app? Also make sure the service account JSON file contains a private key field.

Comment: This is kind of weird. When using the credential created from the Firebase console it does not work, but when I manually created a service account from the Google Cloud Console it works!

Comment: Do you see any major differences in the two credential files?

Comment: None. They contain the same (off course with different values).